# Proper way to use weak references in Python

Tags: python, weak-references

I have two classes Parent and Child. At any point in time, there will only be one Parent but there can be multiple Child objects. The Parent will need to keep reference to the Child objects in a dictionary indexed by the Child name. The Child also needs a reference to the Parent since it can call one of the Parent's functions.

I know that I should use weakref here. I have two ways of doing this:

**Method One**

```
class Child():
    def __init__( self, parent, name ):
        self.parent_ = weakref.proxy( parent )
        self.name_ = name

class Parent():
    def __init__( self ):
        self.children = {}
    def createChild( self, name ):
        self.children[ name ] = Child( self, name )
```

**Method Two**

```
class Child():
    def __init__( self, parent, name ):
        self.parent_ = parent
        self.name_ = name

class Parent():
    def __init__( self ):
        self.children = {}
    def createChild( self, name ):
        self.children[ name ] = Child( weakref.proxy( self ), name )
```

1. Is there difference b/w Method One and Method Two?
2. What is the best way to achieve this functionality?

**Edit**: When the Parent dies, Children should also die. I don't want any Child object to exist if the Parent doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need weak references here? If you used your method one with just

```
self.parent = parent
```

you would achieve what you intend to do. A weak reference to parent would allow the parent object to be destroyed if it isn't referenced anywhere strongly anymore, but in this case children would be unable to call parent's functions as the object wouldn't exist.

Methods 1 and 2 look the same to me.

R

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't put the question clearly. Children wouldn't exist without the Parent.

Comment: If this is the case, then weak references would not be suitable. Use normal, strong references instead.

Comment: Why is that Richard?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but you strongly indicate a parent would need to be present if there are any children. I extrapolate the parent must not be garbage collected as long as any children are in existence.

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your two approaches are equivalent, they evaluate to the exact same result.

Weak references are used, when you want referred objects to be garbage collected even though your (*weak*) references do still exist. In your case, your `Parent` has regular references to your `Child` instances, but the children only hold weak references to their common parent. This means, that -- in certain cases -- the parent would be garbage collected even though there are still children that might want to use it.

I think, you can just use a regular, strong reference here.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your questions:

1. Methods 1 and 2 are equivalent.
2. In general, there is no need to call `weakref.proxy()` directly. In this case you can use a [WeakValueDictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary), which is a:

> Mapping class that references values weakly. Entries in the dictionary will be discarded when no strong reference to the value exists any more.

I think you want this outside of the parent class (since you want it to still be around if the parent is deleted), with keys identifying the children and values giving the parent. So you'd have something like this:

```
registry = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

class Child():
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name

class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def createChild(self, name):
        child = Child(self, name)
        registry[child] = self
```

As an aside, the names `Child` and `Parent` are a bit confusing here - by convention they imply that `Child` inherits from `Parent` (in which case you could just call the parent's method on the child directly and not need the "child" to know the parent's name). What you have here is a **has-a** relationship rather than an **is-a** relationship.